# Making program which compiles given code using g++

Tags: c++, testing, compiler-construction, g++, evaluator

I'm trying to figure out how to make a program that compiles written code using g++ and tests if it runs well with examples.
There will be textbox in program where you enter your code (solution). 
Let's say that exercise was to make a program that calculates sum of 2 numbers.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int a, b;
   cin >> a >> b;
   cout << a + b;
   return 0;
}
```

What that program has to do is make a example.cpp file that includes given code (I'm familiar with that part) and compile example.cpp using g++. When it compiles the program has to somehow enter examples in compiled program and test if result is correct. For example test numbers are 4 and 5 and result has to be 9. (These test numbers can be stored in .txt files or something like that).

```
system("g++ C:\\Users\\%USERNAME%\\Documents\\example.cpp");
```

With this program compiles example.cpp but how to run and test it.

Any ideas? Thanks! :)

Edit: I'm able to run it and input test number in it, the only thing left is to test if output is correct.

```
system("C:\\Users\\%USERNAME%\\Documents\\g++\\example.exe < example.txt");
```

Comment: Do you really want to use c++ for running system commands and examining the output? Sounds like a job for a scripting language of sorts.

Comment: There are nice solutions for this in Unix systems, but it looks like you're running windows. (After "g++ example.cpp" you just say "./a.out << mySampleInput".)

Comment: @SoapCro: `system("example.exe <input.txt >output.txt");` and then load `output.txt` and affirm it has the right number.

Answer (score 0):

It happens that there is a [sample code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499%28VS.85%29.aspx) on MSDN that does almost exactly what you want to accomplish i.e. creates new process and redirects stadard input and output to pipes created by parent.